# Is my partial derivation of MSE loss function correct w.r.t to w1?

Tags: partial-derivative, mean-square-error

$ mse = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i})^2 $
where

$ \hat{y_i} = w_1 * x_{i1} + w_2 * x_{i2} + b $ where $ x_{i1} $ and $ x_{i2} $ and $ b $ are scalars

$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1} mse =  \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1}(y_i - \hat{y_i})^2 $

$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1} mse =  \dfrac{-2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i}) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1} \hat{y_i} $

$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1} mse =  \dfrac{-2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i}) x_{i1} $

$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1} mse =  \dfrac{-2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i}) x_{i1} $

Edit:
Corrected  derivation with guidance from Paul. I tested out the formula with pytorch package below. Pls ignore the below code, this was just my way of validating

```
import torch
from torch.nn import Linear, functional
import numpy as np

red = lambda x:print(f'\x1b[31m{x}\x1b[0m')
X = torch.tensor([[0.1019, 0.0604],
        [1.0000, 0.7681]], dtype=torch.float32)
y = torch.tensor([[1.],
        [0.]], dtype=torch.float32)

xi1 = X.numpy()[:,0].reshape(2,1)
red('xi1')
print(xi1)
red('y')
print(y)
n = len(X)
torch.manual_seed(44)
model = Linear(2,1)
w1, w2 = model.weight[0]
red('Initial weights')
print(f'w1={w1}, w2={w2}')

ycap = model(X)
red('ycap')
print(f'{ycap.detach().numpy()}' )
loss = functional.mse_loss(ycap, y)
loss.backward()
d1, d2 = model.weight.grad[0]
red('partial diff of w1 of mse_loss fn')
print(f'd1={d1}, d2={d2}')

d_x_i1 = - 2/n * np.sum( (y.numpy() - ycap.detach().numpy()) * xi )
red('manual diff of w1 using formula')
print(d_x_i1)

assert d1 == d_x_i1
```

[image]

Comment: You give a definition of $\hat y$, but your calculation does not involve a $\hat y$. It involves a $\hat y_i$. One might suppose you simply dropped the $i$ subscript. But your definition involves both $i$ and $j$ subscripts on the $x$. Where then does $j$ come in? Is it a constant. Later, even though you sum over $i$, you see fit to move $x_i$ out of that sum, though it is apparently dependent on $i$. Something is clearly deficient in your handling of indices, but without knowing more, I cannot say exactly where.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @PaulSinclair. Pls let me know if it looks good now

Comment: Assuming that the $y_i$ themselves can be considered independent of $w_1$, this is correct.

Comment: yes yi and w1 are independent. But could you pls explain why this is an important consideration?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1}(y_i - \hat y_i)^2 = 2(y_i - \hat y_i)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_1}(y_i - \hat y_i) = 2(y_i - \hat y_i)\left(\dfrac{\partial y_i}{\partial w_1} - \dfrac{\partial \hat y_i}{\partial w_1}\right)$$ It is only if $y_i$ is independent of $w_1$ that you can say $\dfrac{\partial y_i}{\partial w_1} = 0$ and reduce the result to  $2(y_i - \hat y_i)\left(-\dfrac{\partial \hat y_i}{\partial w_1}\right)$ as you did.